# LPAD a column with the MAX LENGTH of that column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column of numbers of varying lengths, and I want to pad them with zeroes so that they are all as long as the largest number. Like so:

```
SQL> SELECT LPAD(PROD_ID, 5, 0) AS PROD_ID  
  2  FROM PRODUCTS_TBL;  

PROD_  
----- 
11235  
00119  
00013  
00015  
00222  
00301  
00302  
00303  
00006  
00087  
00009  
00090
```

But I don't want to use the number 5, I want to use a function on PROD_ID, in case it changes later. I tried

```
SQL> SELECT LPAD(PROD_ID, MAX(LENGTH(PROD_ID)), 0)
  2  FROM PRODUCTS_TBL;
```

but

```
SELECT LPAD(PROD_ID, MAX(LENGTH(PROD_ID)), 0)
        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the point, when at some future date (when you roll through a 10^n barrier) all of these numbers get reformatted? Usually, padding like this is applied when trying to create a stable identifier.

Comment: I agree with @Damien -- seems like if you *have* to do this, it should be done on the UI side, not the database side.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, thanks. But for now, I don't have to do it, I just wanted to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm unable to test this myself but what if you try

```
SELECT LPAD(PROD_ID,
            MAX(LENGTH(PROD_ID)) OVER (),
            0)
FROM   PRODUCTS_TBL;
```

Comment: This works if you move the over() outside the max(...): `MAX(LENGTH(PROD_ID)) OVER (),`

Comment: @JohnDoyle - Fixed. Well spotted.

Comment: @jalopezp - Looks like you still have the parentheses in the wrong place. I fixed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Probably best to do that in two steps.  Select the maximum length first in one query, then run a second query that selects the actual data.  It is possible to do it with a join, but it would probably perform poorly.